# How to launch activity only once when app is opened for first time after an update?

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

What would be the most logical way to go about launching an activity when an app is opened for the first time after an update. I understand that a sharedprefs would be the easiest way for this, but sharedprefs are persistent across application updates so it wouldn't seem that that option would work. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you be more clear about your question? So far it sounds like you just want to allow one instance of your application, which could be done through AndroidManifest.xml.

However i'm fairly certain that I did not understand the question entirely.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make the shared pref store the version number of the app: if the version is different, update it and then launch your Activity.

EDIT: this is what I do in my what's new check. It loads up the app info, fetches the version number and if it has changed it pops open the Activity.

```
    public static boolean show(Context c)
    {
        ApplicationInfo ai = c.getApplicationInfo();
        String basis = ai.loadLabel(c.getPackageManager()).toString();
        try {
            PackageInfo pi = c.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(c.getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_META_
DATA);
            SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(c);
            String lastVersion = prefs.getString("lastversion", null);
            SharedPreferences.Editor edit = prefs.edit();
            if(lastVersion == null){
                // save the first installed version so we can check and see when it got installed
                edit.putString("firstversion", String.valueOf(pi.versionCode));
                edit.commit();
            }
            if(lastVersion == null || pi.versionCode > Integer.parseInt(lastVersion)){
                edit.putString("lastversion", String.valueOf(pi.versionCode));
                edit.commit();
                // show it
                Intent i = new Intent(c, WhatsNew.class);
                c.startActivity(i);
                return true;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            android.util.Log.v("WhatsNew", "Exception checking for release notes for [" + basis +
"]:" + e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Great, I appreciate your time.